# Add a period after capital letters followed by a white space

Tags: r, regex, stringr

As the title says, a have a string where I want to add a period after any capital letter that is followed by a whitespace, e.g.:

```
"Smith S Kohli V "
```

would become:

```
"Smith S. Kohli V. "
```

This is as close as I got:

```
v <- c("Smith S Kohli V ")
stringr::str_replace_all(v, "[[:upper:]] ", ". ")

"Smith . Kohli . "
```

I can see I need to add some more code to keep the capital letter, but I can't figure it out, any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this way to capture that match where the capital letter followed by space( ) character and then replace the whole match with an extra `dot(.)`.

```
v <- c("Smith S Kohli V ")
stringr::str_replace_all(v, "([A-Z](?= ))", "\\1.")
```

**Regex:** https://regex101.com/r/uriEYS/1

**Demo:** https://rextester.com/ELKM47734

Answer (score 4):

Base R using `gsub` :

```
v <- c("Smith S Kohli V ")
gsub('([A-Z])\\s', '\\1. ', v)
#[1] "Smith S. Kohli V. "
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `base R`

```
gsub("(?<=[A-Z])\\s", ". ", v,  perl = TRUE)
#[1] "Smith S. Kohli V. "
```

#### data

```
v <- c("Smith S Kohli V ")
```